# Скрипт для смены обоев рабочего экрана с Synology, QNAP

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Как написать скрипт который будет менять обои рабочего стола с QNAP или Synology?

Answer (score 1):

Обои скриптом устанавливаются так

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'
```

картинку нужно предварительно скачать, например

```
wget https://www.qnap.com/assets/img/logo/defualt-sharing.png -O /tmp/wall.png
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///tmp/wall.png
```